# Hourly historical data for US stocks: how to download for free in Python

Tags: python

I have to download last 10 year price data at hourly intervals. I tried trying the link below with
i= 2600 (2600 seconds or 1 hour)
p=10Y or 2500d

https://finance.google.com/finance/getprices?q=LHA&p=10Y&i=3600&f=d,c,h,l,o,v

please can you help me find out how to down hourly data for last 10 year for a stock. If it’s not possible, the longest possible time span ( 1 year ideally) of intraday hourly data will be great too. Can you please help me get the source for this ( this is for my project at and at university and I am looking for free sources )

thanks a lot

Comment: You're unlikely to find this for free. Even Bloomberg, which costs tens of thousands of dollars, only provides a few months of intraday data.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is purely a programming question.

Comment: I am looking for the source of the intraday data. Can only be a few months . Please help

Comment: I haven't found free hourly data. Cheap hourly data is available through https://pitrading.com/, but its definitely not equivalent to paying for premium institutional data.

Answer (score 0):

you can get a trail with iqfeed.net for a week.
there are many free tools to d.l. 1 hour. I don't know how long back it goes but worth a try...